# How to check whether the content(string) of a node is in title case?

Tags: c#

I want to check whether the contents of a node in a xml file is in title case or not. I'm aware that there is a **TextInfo.ToTitleCase** method which converts any string to title case but is there anything like **TextInfo.IsTitleCase** which basically checks the string, whether it is in title case or not?

For example, I have some xml files each having the node `<title>` in one of the below formats(or maybe some other formats, you get the idea)

```
<title>Confer<title>
<title>CONFER<title>
<title>confer<title>
<title>cOnFEr<title>
<title>confeR<title>
```

The program should should check the nodes `<title>`'s content and if it is not in title case, as it is for all the above examples except the first one it should write a message saying something like **"File: xyz..xml ==> Line 100: `<title>cOnFEr<title>` should be in title case"**

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 4):

```
bool IsTitleCase(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        return false;
    return text == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text);
}
```

Comment: @TamalBanerjee There is no line that says `return text == text.ToTitleCase();`

Comment: @TamalBanerjee If you want to disallow all caps, write the method like: `public static bool IsTitleCase(string text) { return text != null && text == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower()); }`

Comment: No problem. I think by default it's allowed because of initialism abbreviations, like UI, POTUS, USA, etc.